# i want to send values to another page using jss page redirection code how can i do that?

Tags: javascript

I am using a button for the redirection to another page and i want to send some value to other page through javascript what will be the method please help me.I am using this code

```
 echo "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:location =\"dalete.php\";' class='button'><font size='1'>Delete</font></button>";
```

Comment: font tag? where did you find this html?

Comment: what are you trying to send? what kind of value? you could append it as a query string to the url you are redirecting to.

Comment: i just want to send some integers values dont have much idea that how i can do that in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it seems you are using some old code. `onclick` is not really used anymore, and has a lot of issues firing in most modern browsers. *And we won't get started about the use of the `<font>` tag here.* But to add a query to the url based on variables it would be something like

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:location =\"dalete.php?myvar=" . $myVar . "\";' class='button'><font size='1'>Delete</font></button>";
```

Or in text

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:location =\"dalete.php?myvar=hello%20world\";' class='button'><font size='1'>Delete</font></button>";
```

On the other end you would retrieve these values in PHP like so `$myVar = $_GET['myvar'];`

I would look into **[jQuery](http://jquery.com)** and it's [`.click()` event](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Remember to sanitize any query on the other end, whether a POST, or URI query via GET.